# How to learn typographic design?

Tags: typography, resource-recommendations

Please suggest some books or some courses I can take online. Given that I know nothing about typography or design.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Lynda.com it is one of the oldest. I found excerpt from this course on youtube 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPCIdtrDagc

These days Canva is quite popular. The platform itself is quite user friendly.

https://designschool.canva.com/blog/typography-design/

Typography is a practice and will improve with your design sense. Try to look out for inspirations.